# How to use a variable from a custom registration form django

Tags: django, registration

I have created a custom registration form in django but i can't seem to use the adress variable in my html code this is what i have for now:

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField (required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    address = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'address',
            'password1',
            'password2',
        )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.address = self.cleaned_data['address']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from accounts.forms import RegistrationForm

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'user_example/index.html')

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            user = authenticate(username= username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()

    context = {'form': form}

    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', context)
```

**Html**

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
Your name is {{ user.username }}
Your address is {{ user.address }}
{% else %}
You are not logged in
{% endif %}
```

And does anyone have an idea of how you make that each field is on a seperate line because for now all the fields of the registration form are on the same line [image]

Comment: Is address part of your `User` model? Can you share the code for your `User` model?

Comment: this ? `    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'address',
            'password1',
            'password2',
        )`

Comment: Where do you plan on storing `address`? Why do you want it as part of the `UserRegistrationForm`? Is there a different model where you plan on storing the address?

Comment: I am creating a shopping website and the address will be used for the delivery i know i can use paypal but i live where paypal is not supported

Comment: Have you extended the `User` model to add the `address` column? How is `user.address = self.cleaned_data['address']` supposed to work? Address is not natively part of the Django `User` Model

Answer (score 0):

As @rtindru is telling you, you need to add `address` to the user model.  Here is one way of doing it.  In this approach, I am replacing the django `auth_user` model with one specific to your app.

In `models.py` add:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
from django.core.mail import send_mail


class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, first_name=None, last_name=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
        )

        user.first_name = first_name
        user.last_name = last_name

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, first_name=None, last_name=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
        )
        user.first_name = first_name
        user.last_name = last_name

        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(
        _('username'),
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[username_validator],
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
    )
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        help_text = "To keep your organisation anonymous you can use a personal email address"
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(
        max_length = 30,
        verbose_name = "First Name",
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
    last_name = models.CharField(
        max_length = 30,
        verbose_name = "Last Name",
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
    address = models.CharField(
        max_length = 255
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'customer_type']

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Sends an email to this User.
        """
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'User'
```

And in `settings.py` add

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
```

Wherever you import the `user` model from `auth_user` you need to import this model instead.

Comment: Do i delete the forms.py ? and what is 'myapp.MyUser' supposed to reffer to

Comment: Here's a link to my project [Download](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pi2jJIY02afnIBQOwjj3ur6TGKTr4oLH) If someone can take a look

Comment: `MyUser` is the new model. `myapp` is the name of your app.  You do not delete `forms.py`.  This should enable it to work

Comment: when i run the server i get django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (username) specified for MyUser

Comment: Sorry, I copied a model I use (which doesn't user `username`.  I've amended now but you could take a copy of AbstractUser in `django.contrib.auth.models.py` and add the `address` field

Comment: So i added a username field in your models and changed USERNAME_FIELD to 'username' and i can do everything but when i submit the register i get an error saying OperationalError at /register
no such table: user_example_myuser

Comment: Have you run `makemigrations` and `migrate`